# How to list index names in pilosa without the complete schema

Tags: pilosa

curl -XGET localhost:10101/index will returns the schema of the specified index in JSON. How can i get only the names of indices present in pilosa without returning the complete schema?

Comment: thank you @monguin , i installed jq using the following command `sudo apt-get install jq`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use a command line tool to parse and filter the JSON response. For example, using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```
curl localhost:10101/schema | jq .indexes[].name
```

will return a quoted list of names, one on each line:

```
"index1"
"index2"
```

You can also pass `-r` to `jq` if you don't want the quotes.